# Node Readline functionality in phantomjs / casperjs

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

Is there an easy way to have interactive user input in a PhantomJS / CasperJS application (arrow keys, command history, tab-completion, etc.)? NodeJS's Readline module (https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) provides much of this functionality, but Casper does not allow importing standard Node modules...

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS supports blocking versions of stdin, stdout and stderr:

```
var system = require("system");

console.log("in: " + system.stdin.readLine());

phantom.exit();
```

You can write your own custom version of REPL with this function.

Comment: `system.stdin.readLine()` does not have Node's readline functionality out of the box (I mean history and navigating the line with arrow keys). Of course it may be possible to write this on top of system.stdin / stdout, but I thought there was a ready solution.

Comment: No, there is no such built-in solution in PhantomJS besides the integrated REPL, but that is unusable. You will need to implement it yourself or see if somebody already implemented such a thing (I highly doubt it).